# Change navigation bar color of CNContactPickerViewController iOS

Tags: ios9, navigationcontroller, cncontact, cncontactviewcontroller

I've home view controller shown in image 1.

[image: Image 1]

When user clicks on bar button another view controller is presented using `presentViewController:` method. This is `CNContactPickerViewController` which is completely native (shown in image 2).

[image: Image 2]

How to change the color of UINavigationBar for this controller?
I've tried below approach but didn't worked :

1. Changed navigation bar color in Appdelegate
2. Changed navigation bar color in global file that is inherited by controller.

I've used below code :

```
 [self.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];

    [self.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NavigationBarBackground"]
                       forBarPosition:UIBarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    [self.navigationBar setShadowImage:[UIImage new]];
    [self.navigationBar setTintColor:kBlackColor];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
      [UIColor blackColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,nil]];
```

Also, when I run the app on device iPhone 6S iOS 9.3.2 the CNContactPickerViewController doesn't shows group button on navigation bar as shown in simulator.

How to change color of `Cancel button on CNContactPickerViewController`?

I've got answer to above question. Now, the pending thing is **how to change color of tableview section as well as cell** of `CNContactPickerViewController`.

Answer (score 4):

Finally, I got it after doing lots of R&D. I've used below code for making *Navigation Bar* of `CNContactPickerViewController` red color.

```
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:NO];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:213/255.0f green:38/255.0f blue:46/255.0f alpha:1.0]];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  [UIColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,nil]];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:kWhiteColor];
```

Comment: This will work fine, but a word of warning that this will change these properties for ALL instances of UINavigationBar, not just the CNContactPickerViewController.